# build a record using a rake task and a ruby code from scraping html

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nokogiri

I use nokogiri to scrap an html page, I am new at scraping like I am new at creating tasks. I have found some tutorials that I thought I'll be able to modify them for my needs, but I can't get it to work.

here is the ruby code that I use to scrap the html, it works nice when I run it in ruby console, but now I need to create a new record with all this fields:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
#require 'pp'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

a.get('http://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:143331-2012:DATA:EN:HTML&tabId=3') do |page|
  title             = page.search('table').search('tr')[0].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }
  doc_nr            = page.search('table').search('tr')[1].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }
  pub_date          = page.search('table').search('tr')[2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }

  puts "#{title} - #{doc_nr} - #{pub_date}"
end
```

would be great to get a complete answer on this, but.. some good links for tutorials and wiki will be ok too. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For activerecord:

```
Record.new(:title => title, :doc_nr => doc_nr, :pub_date => pub_date).save
```

Comment: any ideas on how to get this in a rake task?

Comment: Yes you just put it for example inside of task :scrape do ... end